Add date shipping field with option to block certain dates and add information to admin section and emails
I use the following code to add a shipping date field, with the ability to block certain dates. This works generally fine, however, the information is not added to the admin section of the order and the emails.
Could anyone help me understand which part is missing?
// Register main datepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker' );
function enabling_date_picker() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

    // Load the datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", '', '', false);
}

// Add custom checkout datepicker field
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping', 'datepicker_custom_field' );
function datepicker_custom_field($checkout) {
    $datepicker_slug = 'my_datepicker';

    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper">';

    woocommerce_form_field($datepicker_slug, array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array( 'form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'label' => __('Fecha de entrega'),
        'required' => true, // Or false
    ), '' );

    echo '<br clear="all"></div>';


    // Jquery: Enable the Datepicker
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var dates = ['2024-11-01', '2024-11-02', '2024-11-03'];
        var a = '#<?php echo $datepicker_slug ?>';
        $(a).datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date)
            {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Save custom fields data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'rfds_save_custom_checkout_fields');

function rfds_save_custom_checkout_fields($order_id) {
    if (!empty($_POST['datepicker_custom_field'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_datepicker_custom_field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['datepicker_custom_field']));
    }
}


First, the main mistake is that you need to use "my_datepicker" field name parameter.
Now, you may not use woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta legacy hook anymore, not really compatible with High Performance Order Storage (HPOS). Instead, you can use:

woocommerce_checkout_create_order (has $order and $data arguments),
woocommerce_checkout_order_created (has $order arguments)

So try the following:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_checkout_date_picker_value', 20, 2 );
function save_custom_checkout_date_picker_value( $order, $data ) {
    $datepicker_slug = 'my_datepicker';

    if (isset($_POST[$datepicker_slug]) && !empty($_POST[$datepicker_slug]) ) {
        $order->add_meta_data( 'delivery_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST[$datepicker_slug], true ) );
    }
}

Now you can retrieve and display that delivery date from the WC_Order object, using:
if ( $delivery_date = $order->get_meta('delivery_date') ){
    echo '<p>' . $delivery_date . '</p>';
}

See Save custom checkout delivery time field value in WooCommerce order details answer, to display the delivery date in admin orders, customer orders and email notifications.
